# Meaning of degeneracy in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, eigenvalue

Let $\hat{A}$ be a Hermitian operator that represents the observable $A$. Its eigenstate-equation would be:

$$\hat{A}\psi_n=a_n\psi_n \tag{1}$$

After solving it, we would get a set of the eigenfunctions $\{\psi_n\}$ and eigenvalues $\{a_n\}$ of $\hat{A}$, with $a_i$ the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenstate $\psi_i$, and *vice versa*.

Then, what do we mean when we say that there is *degeneracy*:

1. That, for the same eigenstate $\psi_i$, there are different eigenvalues $a_i$ that verify $(1)$, or
2. That, for the same eigenvalue $a_i$, there are different eigenstates $\psi_i$ that verify $(1)$?

Comment: So, even if the correct option is $(2)$, could happen option $(1)$? Would it make any sense?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- We mean the second option. For the same eigenvalue $a_i$, there are multiple *linearly independent* eigenvectors $\psi_{ij}$ where $j$ denotes the degeneracy. When you measure something, if there are multiple linearly independent states giving the same measurement value, those states are degenerate.
- Also note that the same eigenstate cannot have multiple eigenvalues. It is unique for a given state.
  Suppose that $A \psi_i = a_i \psi_i$ and $A \psi_i = a_i' \psi_i$. Then $a_i \psi_i − a_i' \psi_i = 0 $, which implies that at least one of $a_i - a_i'$ or $\psi_i$ is equal to zero. Eigenvectors are nonzero by definition, so it must be the case that $a_i=a_i'$.
- Operators are linear transformations acting on the Hilbert space. The transformations usually involve stretching, squeezing and rotations. The vectors which still remain on their span after the transformations are the eigenvectors for that operation. In other words, the eigenvectors will stay in the same direction even after applying the operator, although they might be squeezed or stretched. The value by which they stretch (a number > $|1|$) or squeeze (a number < $|1|$) is their eigenvalue. It should be clear now, why we can't have multiple eigenvalues for a vector.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what do we say that it is *degenerate*: the eigenfunctions $\psi_{i,1}, \psi_{i,2},...$ sharing the same eigenstate $a_i$, or the eigenstate $a_i$ associated to the different eigenfunctions $\psi_{i,1}, \psi_{i,2},...$?

Comment: We say that states are degenerate. Also, $a_i$ is not an eigenstate, it is the eigenvalue, a scalar. Eigenstates are column vectors.

Comment: This is all a bit of a long time ago but the $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ hydrogen orbitals are degenerates because they have the same energy value, amiright?

Comment: @Gert, yes, you are right. All orbitals with the same principal quantum number are degenerate, since they have same energy according to non-relativistic Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @Gert, I am very sorry. If you were asking why orbitals $p_x, p_y$ and $p_z$ are degenrate, then this degeneracy due to $m_l$ value owing to the absence of a preferred spatial direction -- valid for any central potential. This is often described as an accidental degeneracy, but it can be explained in terms of special symmetries of the Schrödinger equation which are _only_ valid for the hydrogen atom in which the potential energy is given by Coulomb's law.

Comment: @AbhayHegde I think you must have mis-spoken on your last bullet point here. It is eigenvalues -1 < a < 1 which would correspond to a "squeezing". Negative eigenvalues in general would just point the eigenvector in the opposite direction, not necessary squeeze it.

Comment: When talking about degeneracy I think it is important to stress that it's not just that there are "multiple eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue", but rather that there are "multiple *linearly independent* eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue". Obviously a multiple of any eigenvector is also an eigenvector.

Comment: @aquirdturtle, very important correction. Thank you, I can't believe I did not notice that.

Comment: @printf True, I meant in the sense of direction. I have edited.

Answer (score 5):

We mean (2) : for the same *eigenvalue* $a_i$ there are more than one *eigenfunction* $\psi_i$. In this case one needs an additional index to distinguish different eigenfunctions corresponding to the same eigenvalue:
$$\hat{A}\psi_{n\nu} = a_n\psi_{n\nu}.$$

Answer (score 3):

From a more mathematical point of view, we say there is degeneracy when the *eigenspace* corresponding to a given eigenvalue is bigger than one-dimensional. Suppose we have the eigenvalue equation
$$
\hat A\psi_n = a_n\psi_n\;.
$$
Here $a_n$ is the eigenvalue, and $\psi_n$ is the eigenfunction corresponding to this eigenvalue. But this eigenfunction is of course not uniquely defined: any multiple of $\psi_n$ also satisfies the eigenvalue equation, $\hat A(\lambda\psi_n) = \lambda \hat A\psi_n = \lambda a_n\psi_n = a_n(\lambda\psi_n)$ by linearity. Thus we talk about *eigenspace* belonging to given eigenvalue $a_n$. This eigenspace may be one-dimensional, i.e. every eigenstate must be proportional to $\psi_n$. In this case there is no degeneracy. But is is possible that this eigenspace has dimension higher than 1. For example this eigenspace may be two-dimensional, which means there are two **linearly independent functions**, say $\psi_{n1}$ and $\psi_{n2}$, which are both eigenfunctions of $\hat A$ with eigenvalue $a_n$:
$$
\hat A\psi_{n1} = a_n \psi_{n1}\;,\quad\hat A\psi_{n2} = a_n \psi_{n2}\;.
$$
Then every linear combination of the form $\alpha\psi_{n1} + \beta\psi_{n2}$ is also an eigenstate of $\hat A$ with eigenvalue $a_n$. That is, the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $a_n$ has dimension 2. In this case we say there is (double) degeneracy.